# Join table in Doctrine without Entity

Tags: doctrine, symfony, dql

I have a problem which I can't solve. 
I have an entity, to which I'm trying to join a table:

```
 /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="FeaturedAttribute")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="property_featured_attribute",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="property", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="featured_property", referencedColumnName="id")})
     */
```

I need to join table table with name `property_featured_attribute` in my DQL-code:

```
LEFT JOIN property_featured_attribute pfa WITH pfa.property = p.id
WHERE pfa.featured_property IN (:attrs)
```

The problem is, that this table - property_featured_attribute - hasn't Entity, so I get an error like:

> 'Error: Class 'property_featured_attribute' is not defined.'

Is it possible to join table without entity in my DQL-query?

Comment: Sadly as of 2023 you still need to a) create an Entity for the other side or b) join it through DBAL c) create a VIEW in DB with the join(s) and use that as a source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this using DQL, because purpose of DQL is to make queries over your object model. DQL is a query language for your object model, not for your relational schema.

But you can make plain query using DBAL:

```
$conn = $this->get('database_connection');
$res = $conn->query('SELECT...');
```